# base64 decode of non https session cookie

Tags: encryption, base64, session-cookies

I am trying to base64 decode of the following cookie from CTF challenge as a learning exercise

> %2BiEftn9TF4DIoUwhXQRsXk1ipRbOigvD1H%2BINemWOLQpoPksFJSnLozS86thQ/wfH7V3Dhb/s2rZrbvlKJSpTJh9SJ3iAhFPOj5cymG6N3kGMRNBeYLs8SKxMxydtqaX

This cookie contains a flag that needs to be decrypted. I tried using the following command in Linux but it returns garbage

```
echo "%2BiEftn9TF4DIoUwhXQRsXk1ipRbOigvD1H%2BINemWOLQpoPksFJSnLozS86thQ/wfH7V3Dhb/s2rZrbvlKJSpTJh9SJ3iAhFPOj5cymG6N3kGMRNBeYLs8SKxMxydtqaX" | base64 -d
```

I know `%` is not a base64 character. How can I decode this cookie since it contains `%` and get the flag that can be further decrypted?

Following Luke Josha Park's suggestion, I did the following in Chrome Developer's console

```
cookie=atob('+iEftn9TF4DIoUwhXQRsXk1ipRbOigvD1H+INemWOLQpoPksFJSnLozS86thQ/wfH7V3Dhb/s2rZrbvlKJSpTJh9SJ3iAhFPOj5cymG6N3kGMRNBeYLs8SKxMxydtqaX
')
```

and I am getting

```
"ú!¶SÈ¡L!]l^Mb¥ÎÃÔ5é8´) ù,§.Òó«aCüµwÿ³jÙ­»å(©L}HâO:>\Êaº7y1Ayìñ"±3¶¦"
```

How to make sense of it or have I done it incorrectly?

Comment: The result you have after URL decoding is the result - whether you expected it or not.  I suggest you view it in a hex editor and see if you can spot any patterns.  Without more context, it is difficult to help you further.

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark can you review this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55165915/decrypting-non-https-session-cookie-error

Answer (score 1):

`%2B` is the URL encoding of the symbol `+`, which **is** a base64 character.  Try URL decoding your original string to produce:

```
+iEftn9TF4DIoUwhXQRsXk1ipRbOigvD1H+INemWOLQpoPksFJSnLozS86thQ/wfH7V3Dhb/s2rZrbvlKJSpTJh9SJ3iAhFPOj5cymG6N3kGMRNBeYLs8SKxMxydtqaX
```